# Two versions of gdal_merge and two diffrent effects

Tags: gdal, gdal-merge

Is there any possibility that two diffrent versions of gdal (1.7.3 and I believe 1.9.0) can give me two diffrent results with given:

- two RGB files.Each twith 3 layers - input1.png and input2.png
- command `gdal_merge -o output_file.img -of HFA -separate input1.png input2.png`

On version 1.9.0 i get 6 layered img file (3layers + 3 layers). On gdal 1.7.3 i get somehow 2 layers (not six) and i cannot recognize which layer is from which image.

These are really the same input files (i literally copied them to diffrent computer) and i used gdal from command line. What's funny is that it works good on windows, and on one ubuntu but on the other ubuntu it works not as predicted. It's the last idea i come with (diffrent gdal versions), but i find it very strange and unbelivable that same program works so much diffrently on diffrent versions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two different version of GDAL_merge do behave differently.  I ran into a similar problem ([see this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34863/gdal-merge-produces-incomplete-mosaic)), though yours appears to be a little different.

Basically, I think that the more recent version is the one to trust.  The reason it works differently is because thankfully it has been updated, so it should not be unbelievable.

Comment: +1 I'd also favor the more recent builds. As for differences between the 1.7.x releases and 1.8+, I recall a series of discussions in the GDAL dev mailing list noting issues specifically affecting `HFA` outputs, a quick search found [this one](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2011-January/027238.html) and [this one](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-FWTools-and-GDAL-1-7-0-td3746493.html).